# GAM goodness-of-fit under covariates shift

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, generalized-additive-model

I have GAM models that were fitted using [PyGAM](https://github.com/dswah/pyGAM) and its [defaults](https://pygam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/lineargam.html?highlight=default) for fitting a linear GAM. To validate the model I do a leave-one-out cross-validation looking at either a  Spearman's rank correlation coefficient or Chi-squared test. I report the final values of these quantities as my goodness-of-fit.

Now, assuming I *cannot* train the models anymore (cost, not enough data, etc.), I want to use the trained ones in new datasets. For these datasets *I am allowed to assume* the independent variables behave in the same way the ones from the training dataset did. This loosely means that the parameters obtained if the GAM was trained again would be similar to the ones I already have.

Since the data/relationship is similar but not the same, I believe I need to 'correct' my goodness-of-fit value. The question is: What's the most reasonable way, if there's any, that I can 'extrapolate' this goodness-of-fit value? My baseline at the moment is simply computing a correlation between the two datasets and use this value to 'correct' the goodness-of-fit I obtained when training the model in the first dataset.

I'm aware that what I'm trying to to has lots of caveats, I just want to know if there's any way I can make it 'less wrong'. Criticism regarding the previous steps are also welcomed, since I'm aware they might be wrong but not by how much or why exaclty.

Edit: as Frans Rodenburg pointed out in the comments, all I wrote above actually means I want to assess the reliability of the predictions given a covariate shift.

Comment: What is the purpose of this model? Inference? Prediction?

Comment: @FransRodenburg prediction.

Comment: In that case, why not do away with the goodness-of-fit measures in favour of a measure of predictive accuracy like RMSE on the new data?

Comment: @FransRodenburg too few data points, for which i also do not have the dependent variable values (unlabeled if you will), thats why i said i cannot train a model there.

Comment: So you're asking how to determine the reliability of a prediction in case of a covariate shift? If so, maybe you can edit your question to emphasize that, so it will attract better answers.

Comment: @FransRodenburg thats exactly it, in a way better phrasing, thank you! ill edit it!